# How to create property methods in django models dynamically?

Tags: python, django, methods, properties, abstract-class

I am creating property methods for every model where the model attribute includes ImageField or FileField. So, I decided to make an abstract model where I check the fields in the model and if there are any ImageField and FileField in the model the property method creates it automatically by itself.

I usually add '_url' to the attribute when I create the method

Below is what I do usually

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(...)
    file = FileField(...)
    ...

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
            return self.image.url


    @property
    def file_url(self):
        if self.file and hasattr(self.file, 'url'):
            return self.file.url

    ...
```

Below what I did so far

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    

    def __new__(cls, value):
        fields = self._meta.get_fields()
        for field in fields:
            if isinstance(field, ImageField) or isinstance(field, FileField):
                ???
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mixins.

```py
class ImageUrlMixin:

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        if self.image and hasattr(self.image, "url"):
            return self.image.url

class FileUrlMixin:

    @property
    def file_url(self):
        if self.file and hasattr(self.file, "url"):
            return self.file.url

class FileImageUrlMixin(FileUrlMixin, ImageUrlMixin):
    pass

class OnlyHasFileFieldModel(FileUrlMixin, models.Model):
    # ..model implementation

class OnlyHasImageFieldModel(ImageUrlMixin, models.Model):
    # ..model implementation

class HasBothFileAndImageFieldModel(FileImageUrlMixin, models.Model):
    # ..model implementation
```

Or if you want to support fields dynamically e.g. `my_model.arbitrary_field_url`:

```py
class DynamicFieldUrlMixin:

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.endswith("_url"):
            field_name = "".join(name.split("_")[:-1])
            field = getattr(self, field_name, None)
            if hasattr(field, "url"):
                return field.url
        raise AttributeError
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the attribute names can change. 
I don't have only image or file name. I can create an attribute like 
class MyModel():
    some_file_field_name = FileField() 
etc.

Comment: You can change the properties (@property) to be standard methods and pass an attribute name instead, to make them more dynamic. Is that sufficient for your aims? I can update my answer to exemplify if so.

Comment: It doesn't need to have @property, they can be just normal methods for the class

Comment: If you want to use different field names yet also have @property style access, you could override `__getattr__` with custom logic.